# how to get row's id of table through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my table HTML

```
<table id="list" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" tabindex="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_list" style="width: 1702px;">
 <tbody>
 <tr class="jqgfirstrow" style="height:auto" role="row">
 <tr id="141" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">
 <tr id="144" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">
 <tr id="147" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight"    tabindex="0" role="row" aria-selected="true">
</tbody>
 </table>
```

i want to get the ids of all three rows(i.e 141,144,147) using jquery. i have tried .find .closest but uptill now havent got any success.

Comment: When do you want to get the id actually..?

Comment: From what I remember <tr> tags need to be closed and can you specify the event that will be calling the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Has-Attribute**](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector

```
$("#list tr[id]").each(function(){
   // Using alert just to show the result
   alert(this.id);
});
```

This will select `tr` which have `id` attribute

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G4pEV/)

Comment: Please don't abuse `alert` like a debug statement

Comment: @RUJordan I dont do it. Many times OP are so new to know about `console.log`

Comment: Advocating it is just like using it ;)

Comment: @RUJordan yah but answer is of no use if OP cant get it

Comment: One of the first things a JS developer learns is debugging. Not knowing about something isn't an excuse to promote poor practice.

Comment: @RUJordan: Yes people should. But now a days it seems like people starts coding without learining anything. Everyday I see lots of such *How to...* question which can be solved with very basic understanding

Comment: @RUJordan Anyways I have added a comment in my answer

Comment: Don't let other peoples poor learning inhibit you from posting proper answers. They'll learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var ids = $('#list').find('tr').map(function(){ return $(this).attr('id'); });
```

or:

```
var ids = $('#list').find('tr[id]').map(function(){ return this.id; });
```

Output:

```
[141, 144, 147]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KbEyk/

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `this.id`?

Comment: `this.id` will returns empty id for `<tr class="jqgfirstrow">`

Comment: And what does `attr` return on an id-less element?

Comment: It returns nothing. Output array's length in my case is `3`. With `this.id` is `4`

Comment: @RUJordan I've added alternative solution for `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list tr").each(function(obj){
 alert(obj.id);
});
```

Comment: This will select *all tr's*

Comment: Yes. all tr under table with ID = "list"

Comment: and its not desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var idArr = [];
  $("tr").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")){
      idArr.push($(this).attr("id"));
    }      
  });
  console.log(idArr)
});
```

Here is the [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4TaJ/) for above code